# start-backup-job issue with permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I hope someone could help me with this. I am experiencing a weird issue while using AWS cli for starting on-demand backup.
I already have some backup jobs running for EC2 instances. However, for some automation i wanted to have on-demand backups as well. For said reason, when i am trying to backup using cli i am getting error.

*An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartBackupJob operation: Insufficient privileges to perform this action.*

The command i am using is;

aws backup start-backup-job --backup-vault-name primary --resource-arn arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123456789:volume/vol-0abcdef1234 --iam-role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/service-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole --region eu-west-1

The user i am using here has administrator access to the account.

Can someone please help me? I am out of options here.

Answer (score 1):

As you can assign `AccessPolicy` to the `Backup Vault` check if you have any policy assigned to the vault you are trying to access. Both should be allowing `IAM Policy` with your admin user as well as the `Resource-Based Policy` assigned to your `Backup Vault`

[Setting Access Policies on Backup Vaults and Recovery Points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/creating-a-vault-access-policy.html)

I did not have any policy assigned to the `Backup Vault` and was able to create the backup, Plus I also have `Admin` access like you.

```sh
$ aws backup start-backup-job --backup-vault-name primary \
--resource-arn arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:1234567890:volume/vol-04a514599941274c3 \
--iam-role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole --region us-east-1
```

```json
{
    "BackupJobId": "5435950f-2be1-4177-92dc-7bsddsdd",
    "CreationDate": "2021-02-04T16:25:03.370000+01:00"
}
```

[How can I use the AWS CLI to create an AWS Backup plan or run an on-demand job?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-backup-cli-create-plan-run-job/)

Last but not least check your environment if the credentials you think should be used are actually getting used by using [sts get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html)